# Java, switch case and array

Tags: java, arrays, switch-statement, case

If i am using a switch case can i make a condition where you have to do the 1st case first and then you can do the 2nd case? if in the first case there's array can i use it in the 2nd case?

```
switch (input) {
        case 1:
            System.out.print("How many data you want :");
            int num = in.nextInt();
            int data[] = new int[num];
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                System.out.print("Input data-"+(i+1)+":");
                data[i]=in.nextInt();
            }
            break;
```

I want to make 2nd case where i can print my data which i input in the first case

Comment: Remove the `break;` and the code will "fall-through" to the next `case`.

Comment: To be able to use the array declared in the first case, you'd need to define it outside of the entire `switch` statement.

Comment: if i declared array outside the switch case, should i declared the array length too? how can i make an array that the length is input manually from user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `data` as the instance variable of the class. and access through the whole switch cases

```
int[] data = null;
switch (input) {
        case 1:
            System.out.print("How many data you want :");
            int num = in.nextInt();
            data = new int[num];
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                System.out.print("Input data-"+(i+1)+":");
                data[i]=in.nextInt();
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
            break;
}
```

Comment: should i input the array length too?

Comment: You can create object inside the case, so only declaring instance name outside of the switch is enough; above code should work, try it and let me know, if you have any problems on it

Comment: i have problems when i try to use the array inside the case,cannot find symbol?

Comment: still error on data[]= new int[num]; , not a statement error?

Comment: Really? I tried above code and it works fine to me, Are you sure you are using above updated code?

Comment: yeah i did, wait what should i do with the data[]? there's recommendation to create class "data"?

Comment: Hi, I am really sorry, There was a small mistake in my code. I edited now. Could you please try it now?